# LibreOffice Writer - Load file from command line (CLI) and save it

Tags: command-line, libreoffice

I noticed that LibreOffice Writer has a good quality: when loading a .docx file, and saving it right away, someone the saved file structure is a bit different than the original file - in a good way - it kinda like solve some .docx structure issues, etc (which allows me later to process it better with Apache POI).

I would like to simply use it to fix .docx files, by loading them and saving them right away - either from the command line, or somehow by invoking the Writer functions directly.

Would appreciate some pointers to the solution.

Comment: Yes, I just didn't find how to specify the output file (only the output dir)..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `libreoffice` CLI tool, it has a `--convert-to` option to convert files which can be used to convert to the same format as you want. If you use this without specifying an output directory it *overwrites* the original file though, and you can’t give it a different output filename. Work around that by converting the file to `/tmp/` first and move it back afterwards:

```
libreoffice --convert-to docx --outdir /tmp/ NAME.DOCX && mv /tmp/NAME.DOCX ./NEWNAME.DOCX
```

You just need to change the bold all-caps parts, **`NAME.DOCX`** to your input filename and **`NEWNAME.DOCX`** to the desired output filename.

On the `bash` command line, you can shorten this to:

```
libreoffice --convert-to docx --outdir /tmp/ NAME.DOCX && mv !#:4!#:5 ./NEWNAME.!#:2
```

This uses [`bash` History Expansion](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#history%20expansion) so that you don’t have to enter paths and filenames multiple times – you just need to change **`NAME.DOCX`** to your input filename and **`NEWNAME`** to the desired output filename without the extension.